# Optimize Arquillian performance when running multiple tests

Tags: unit-testing, jakarta-ee, jboss-arquillian

I am using Arquillian for testing Java EE application against Glassfish, So far I am facing a performance problem, each Test case takes more than a minute to complete, having 60 Test cases means an hour to run. and hence the build will take more an hour.

I understand that running a test case might take this time in starting a glassfish container, creating and deploying a war file.

Is there a way to group test cases under each project, add all of the classes, create a single Deployment archive and run multiple tests in a single deployment as if they are a single test class?

Answer (score 7):

Arquillian does not support suites by itself.

But I wrote extension that makes suites testing possible.

https://github.com/ingwarsw/arquillian-suite-extension

There you should find documentation with examples.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using an embedded glassfish instance? Because running a remote instance should work faster.

Comment: yes I am using embedded glassfish, A single test class which contains about 4 test cases takes more than 1 minute to run.

Comment: I think even if I use a remote instance, the test still will be slow. Creating a war archive for each test case and deploying it is slow. I need to package several test cases into one archive and run them once.

Answer (score 0):

Use a test suite (`@Suite`) and set up your arquillian container in a `@BeforeClass` annotated method

see http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-tutorial-5-suite-test/

Edit :

And if all your class extend an AbstractTestClass which declare the `@BeforeClass` annotated method which initialize the container only if it's not already done ?

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work that way as test suite requires @RunWith(Suite.class) while arquillian requires @RunWith(Arquillian.class)

Comment: hey Gab, arquillian doesn't use @BeforeClass() to to create the deployment, instead it has @Deployment(), tried to use it in the Suite class but test cases didn't run.

Comment: it is funny stack overflow doesn't allow me to add @BeforeClass seems they understand that I am talking to somebody names BeforeClass :)